# Hatched lines in table of signs

Tags: tkz-tab

So i want to create a hatched line in the table, the table should look like this:
[image: wanted output]

Instead the closest thing i could make is this:
[image: result instead]
This is what i wrote:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\tikzset{t style/.style={style=solid}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzTabInit[lgt=3,espcl=2,deltacl=0]
        { $x$ /.8, $2x^2+8x+6$ /.8, $x^2+2x$ /.8, $$\frac{2x^2+8x+6}{x^2+2x}$$ / 2}
        {$\qquad-\infty$,$-3$,$-2$,$-1$,$0$,$+\infty\qquad$} % four main references
    \tkzTabLine {,+,z,-,t,-,z,+,t,+,} % seven denotations
    \tkzTabLine {,+,t,+,z,-,t,-,z,+,}
    \tkzTabLine {,+,z,-,d,+,z,-,d,+,}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution with `{NiceArray}` of `nicematrix` and TikZ.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}
$\begin{NiceArray}{|c|*{4}{w{c}{1.2cm}w{c}{1mm}}w{c}{1.2cm}|}[hlines]
  x         & \multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{-\infty}
                & -3 &   & -2 &   & -1 &   & 0 &  \multicolumn{1}{r@{\hspace{2pt}}}{+\infty} \\
  2x^2+8x+6 & + & 0  & - &    & - &  0 & + &   & + \\
  x^2+2x    & + &    & + &    & - &    & - & 0 & + \\
  \frac{2x^2+8x+6}{x^2+2x} 
            & + & 0  & - &    & + &  0  & - &   & + 
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture}
     \draw (2-|3.5) -- (5-|3.5) ;
     \draw (2-|5.5) -- (4-|5.5) ;
     \draw [pattern = north west lines] ([xshift=-2pt]4-|5.5) rectangle ([xshift=2pt]5-|5.5) ;
     \draw (2-|7.5) -- (5-|7.5) ;
     \draw (2-|9.5) -- (4-|9.5) ;
     \draw [pattern = north west lines] ([xshift=-2pt]4-|9.5) rectangle ([xshift=2pt]5-|9.5) ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]